# Check if the highest value is present in a range of columns with postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am looking for a way to check if the highest value in a row is present in one of the columns with postgresql. For Example:

[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCNEf.png)

Is the highest value present in the column `perc_20-25` in my table example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In most versions of SQL, the max function is intended to be applied across _rows_, not columns.  I would say you have a design problem here.  The code needed to compare every column will be ugly I expect.

Comment: please post the table schema, and also the expected output. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer